# In Java 8 Namespace prefix gets changed when running with Woodstox

Tags: java, xml, java-8, xml-namespaces, woodstox

I have a simple Java program as below which reads an xml file and prints it in the console:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/test.xml"));
InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
OMXMLParserWrapper builder = BuilderUtil.getBuilder(streamReader);

SOAPEnvelope envelope = (SOAPEnvelope)builder.getDocumentElement();
//the namespace prefix is OK here (java 7 and java 8)
System.out.println(envelope.getHeader().getChildrenWithLocalName("Ticket").next());

//but after the toString() method, the prefix has modified (java 7 = not change, java 8 = change)
//attribute mustUnderstand and role
System.out.println(envelope.toString());
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <S:Header>
        <abc:Ticket xmlns:abc="somevalue" xmlns:uebernehmeAbschlussdatenXBRL="abcSomevalue" S:mustUnderstand="true" S:role="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/role/next">
            <abc:value>long value</abc:value>
        </abc:Ticket>   
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body>    
        <sample>data</sample>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

When I run the program in Java 7 with **woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1, stax2-api-3.1.4** and **axiom** it works fine.
But when I run the same thing in Java 8, S:role and S:mustunderstand get change as env:role and env:mustunderstand (**S prefix get changed to env**)

If I remove the **woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1** and **stax2-api-3.1.4** from the program, it works fine in Java 8 as well.

I can't figure out the issue here. Does this imply that woodstox doesn't support Java 8 or am I missing something else?

Comment: Please add information about the Axiom version that you use and provide the code of the `BuilderUtil.getBuilder` method.

Comment: I'm using axiom 1.2.11 version which is an OSGi bundle embedded with woodstox

Comment: why did I get a -1 for this?

Answer (score 2):

Prefix `S` and `env` in your document both map to the same namespace URI `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope`.

So even if the prefix has changed in the serialized document it is still equivalent to the one with preserved prefixes.

(The reason for the change could be in the DOM implementation of Java 8, something like a different ordering of the namespace declarations.)

Comment: Yes here the namespace are same. But the problem is signature validation returns false since the prefix has been changed

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne why do have a doubled namespace declaration?

Comment: Though the namespace are equal in theh example I put there can be situation where it is like xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:env="http://abc/example". I dont have a control over the number of namespaces :/

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne if they point to different uris then the serialized document will not change prefixes...

Comment: I agree with you wero. But I still wonder why it works with Java 7 but not with 8. Do you think the DOM implementation in java 7 contains an issue and it is fixed in java 8?

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne no issue, but maybe just an reordering of the ns decls. You could try to switch the order of the ns decls in the document, and then serialize. If my theory is true the prefixes in the output should also switch

Comment: I tried that as well. still it uses env prefix instead of S prefix. I suspect this might  be a issue with the woodstox implementation. Because when I remove woodstox library and use jdk provided implementation then it works

Comment: I do not know (and I'm the author of Woodstox...), but would guess that this is due to JDK change related to either String hash code calculation, or ordering of `HashMap` entries. Given that there are 2 equivalent namespaces with different prefixes, ordering of the two could result in different match when Axiom asks for prefix for given namespace URI; after all, BOTH map to same prefix, and since ordering of attributes (of which namespace prefix declaration is special case) is undefined in XML (that is, thre is no ordering) either one is valid.

Comment: @StaxMan thanks for the info. If you put this as explanation in your answer I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: @wero: Axiom doesn't use DOM.

Answer (score 1):

One basic thing to note here is this: using `envelope.toString()` isn't really reliably way of testing anything, as it is not clear what exactly is being printed. Woodstox does not change prefixes reported, so it is unlikely it would expose different prefix: more likely case is that Axiom builds envelope and maps given namespace URI back to different prefix, given that there are 2 choices.

So: I would guess that this is due to JDK change related to either String hash code calculation, or ordering of HashMap entries. Given that there are 2 equivalent namespaces with different prefixes, ordering of the two could result in different match when Axiom asks for prefix for given namespace URI; after all, BOTH map to same prefix, and since ordering of attributes (of which namespace prefix declaration is special case) is undefined in XML (that is, thre is no ordering) either one is valid

Without Woodstox dependency, processing probably uses JDK-embedded Stax parser (sjsxp), and ordering it exposes may be either accidentally stable, or use a mechanism that is not hash-based.

Comment: I used prefix S and R (instead of env) Then it works without any issue. It seems that this is goes with hash value calculation in Java 8. But I still can't understand why it is working with axiom without any issue when removing woodstax embedded dependnecy

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne if Woodstox is not included, processing would probably rely on JDK-embedded stax parser (Sjsxp), which may use different mechanism, and thereby different ordering of attributes and namespace prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected prefixes are caused by an issue in old versions of Apache Axiom (1.2.11 is more than 5 years old). You should upgrade to 1.2.15 or a later version.

Axiom used to use a `HashMap` to store namespace declarations; that may be the reason why for a given message, you only see the issue with certain Java versions.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yeah. It seems that the issue is fixed in axiom 1.2.15. Could you point out the jira or the fix? :) I checked the release note but couldnt figure out the exact fix https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12311190&version=12318876

Comment: Unfortunately not. I remember that I fixed several namespace related issues, but I think they weren't reported as JIRA issues; they came up while debugging other issues or reviewing/refactoring code. If you really need to identify the exact commit that fixed the issue you would have to use something like git bisect.

Comment: that is sad :( I will try to check that. thanks for the info @Anreas. By any chance do you remember what sort of package or class that you fixed? ;) if so please let me know. So as I understand this is caused due to the hanshcode changes in JDK + some bug in axiom right?